# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + buildbot: how to fix dependencies problem?

Tags: apt, python

I have `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` and buildbot 0.8.12-3.

I tried start buildbot like this:

```
cd /var/lib/buildbot/masters/
sudo buildbot create-master test
cd test/
sudo cp master.cfg.sample master.cfg
sudo buildbot start
```

And as output I got:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: Requirements are not satisfied for buildbot.buildslave:BuildSlave: (sqlalchemy-migrate 0.10.0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2'))
```

And only buildbot uses python-sqlalchemy and python-migration

```
$ aptitude why python-sqlalchemy
i   buildbot Depends python-sqlalchemy (< 1.1)
```

So looks like nobody even runs buildbot before packaging.

What the best way to fix this issue? Install `pip` and using it to install right version of sqlalchemy or download sources of package, fix it and rebuild, maybe other options?

Comment: Did you try [The Easy Way](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/DownloadInstall#TheEasyWay) for installing buildbot ?

Comment: @Bilal The easy way involve `pip`,  so I lost all automatic update, files tracking and so on features from `apt-get`. But may be if they not even start buildbot guys from ubuntu is useless for buildbot support, so I doubt  what to do, and that's why this is question.

Comment: @user1034749 Indeed, `pip -U` allows upgrading. I have found that language-specific package managers (like pip) have a better track record for keeping packages up-to-date, as well as convenience and reliability, than apt-get. But, I'm speaking as a programmer, who often needs the latest versions of obscure libraries and tools.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using `pip` with a package that provides virtual environments such as `virtualenv`.

1. Install `virtualenv` if you haven't:

   ```
   sudo apt install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a directory for your project and `cd` to it.
3. Create a virtual environment called `venv` and then activate it:

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   source venv/bin/activate
   ```
4. Install `buildbot` using `pip` (this will pull in the required dependencies like `sqlalchemy`):

   ```
   pip install buildbot
   ```
5. Try the Buildbot tutorial at http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html to make sure Buildbot is working as expected.
6. After you are done using the virtual environment, deactivate it:

   ```
   deactivate
   ```

Comment: And how you work with it on every day basis, have you `systemd` service file for it, if no, how you make sure that it start if you need reboot system?

Comment: @user1034749 I am pretty sure you can achieve that, but I am not familiar with the specifics since I haven't done it before myself and so I am reluctant to provide an absolute answer. There are plenty of questions on this site regarding starting a service with `systemd`, so search around and ask a question if you can't find a solution. I personally don't use `buildbot` but I did try to install it to answer your question about installing it. :)